# Is there another word for “deported person”?

Tags: word-request, nouns, synonyms

I am looking for another word for *deported person*, or a short form of saying it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word is *deportee* but you don't want to use that outside of a legal or political context, it's very uncommon in casual conversation. Normally we just say "he/she was deported" rather than using a specific noun.

Comment: Why do you say that?  Do a search on *deportee* in Google News it shows up all over the place.  Arlo Guthrie even has a song entitled ["Deportee"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deportee_%28Plane_Wreck_at_Los_Gatos%29)

Comment: Thank you, this is the word I was searching for. @Jim, interesting song by the way.

Comment: @Jim Woody G, please!

Comment: @StoneyB- Yeah, you are right.  I had originally typed Woody, but second guessed myself when I found [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2eO65BqxBE)

Comment: It is used in legal/political context only. It's misleading to suggest it's a common word in general. For instance, you wouldn't say *What? Your sister is a deportee??* Of course not. You would say, *What?? Your sister was deported?*

Comment: I'm not sure if we should assume that all English learners are only interested in speaking colloquially. Wouldn't many be interested in immigration law, business, etc; and just understanding what they hear in any context?

Comment: ....exactly. Hence this question and answer. But it should be *noted* that this is not a colloquial word.

Comment: -ee words are not in any way legal, governmental or technical. This is part of the English morphology, shared by all speakers. Often when we have a an X-er word, we can form X-ee. Or from many types of verbs V we can form V-ee. Someone who asks a question: asker. The target of a question: askee. Someone doesn't have to be aware of any legal or governmental terminology to deduce the word deportee from deport. Sometimes -ee constructions are in jest or tongue in cheek. "Now wait, who are you calling a fucker here! The way I see it, I'm rather the fuckEE in this situation, haha!".

Comment: Be that as it may, they are by and large used in a legal context far, *far* more than colloquially. To suggest otherwise is silly.

Answer (score -1):

In case you were tempted to use the abbreviation DP, just like to note a potential confusion:  the acronym 'DP' as in 'DP camp', referring to groups of Eastern European war refugees in Germany in the aftermath of WWII, stands for 'displaced persons'.  Not that any comment in this thread confused them, but just pointing it out.  As a term 'DP' most likely would be confined to this historical context - I'm not sure if 'displaced persons' is still used in the context of international human rights etc or not.